# Few questions related to Thread Join

Tags: multithreading

This is my simple program using Threads

```
public class ThreadJoinExample implements Runnable 
{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            try {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {

        ThreadJoinExample threadjoinex  = new ThreadJoinExample();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(threadjoinex,"Th1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(threadjoinex,"Th2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(threadjoinex,"Th3");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
                t3.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    }


}
```

I have few questions listed below related to above program

1.

Will the Order (start and join methods ) will make any difference ?? Or it can be any way

```
t1.start();
t1.join();

t2.start();
t2.join();

t3.start();
t3.join();
```

2. I have read that If a Thread T2 wants to start only after Thread T1 Finishes then 
   T1.join() should be called from the Thread T2 File??

If so then the above program code is useless as everything (join)is called from the same file ??

3. The Output of  above program doesn't have any order 
   Is it possible to print them in a order ?? (Below way )

   ```
   Th1
   Th2
   Th3

   Th1
   Th2
   Th3

   Th1
   Th2
   Th3

   Th1
   Th2
   Th3
   ```

Comment: It's really hard to make sense of your questions. Do you understand what `start` and `join` do? If not, why not ask that? If so, what don't you understand exactly?

Comment: Sorry if my questions troubled you ,i am aware ofthese two methods start and join .  My intention is that if i call T2.join the current Threads execution will wait until T2 has finished.

Comment: Right, that's exactly what join does. It causes the calling thread to wait until the joined thread finishes.

Comment: So exactly my First question is ,in case if i do t1.start , t2.start and t3.start and do t1.join ,t2.join and t3.join later . What is the guarantee that t2 and t3 didn't call their run methods  ?? so i might lose the order know??

Comment: If you want the things done in order, why are you having them be done by separate threads?!

Comment: My actual requirement is One Thread Reads from a File , Second Thread Calculates those and the Third THread writes the computed value to the File , so i need the Threads to be executed in a order.so just experimenting with sample example

Comment: Why is it that the first thing everyone tries to do with threads is to completely defeat the entire purpose of having threads?!

Comment: I don't know about everybody ,but can i have answer for my question.

Comment: What's your question? It seems like you understand what these functions do.

Comment: Thanks for  answering patiently , Well my question is how to achieve the Order of Thread Execution in my case ?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. You could have each thread create the next thread when it's done. You could create all the threads then have each thread wait for the previous thread when it starts. But these are all bone-headed solutions because your requirements are bizarre and artificial. There's no good way to give you a good answer without understanding the expectations you are supposed to meet. For example, I could suggest an assembly line pattern, but that might not be what whoever asked you to do this in this particular way expects.

Comment: If all the start / join calls are on the same thread, if you call: `thread1.start()    thread1.join()    thread2.start()` then thread2 will not be started until thread1 has terminated as your calling thread is stuck in thread1.join()